# Exclusion limits for axion-like particle

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, astrophysics, axion

Suppose the **axion-like field** $\theta$ with lagrangian
$$
\tag 1 
L = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\theta)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}m_{\theta}^{2}\theta^{2} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\theta}{f_{\gamma}}F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\alpha\beta},
$$
where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is EM field strength tensor, and $\tilde{F}^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta \rho \sigma}F_{\rho \sigma}$ is the dual one.

I'm interested in a question whether some experiment or observation excludes the theory $(1)$ for a range $f_{\gamma} < \text{ GeV}$, $m_{\theta} < 10^{-3}\text{ eV}$, i.e., long-living in vacuum but strongly interacting axion-like particles. Could you help?

Comment: Axion-photon oscillations via the [Primakoff effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primakoff_effect) has been used to contain axions. E.g. x-rays can be converted to axions inside the Sun and on Earth you can then try to regenerate the original X-rays in a strong magnetic field. This can be done underground at nighttime when the axions from the Sun would be moving through the Earth to your detector.    Null results from such experiments have been used to constrain the possible coupling constants and axion masses.

Comment: @CountIblis : but whether axions with very large coupling pass all the path from internal part of the sun to the Earth? Also, for large couplings the probability of oscillation behaves as $P_{\gamma\to \theta}= \sin^2\left(\frac{BL}{f_{\gamma}}\right) \approx \sin^2\left(\frac{BL}{\text{Tl}\cdot\text{m}} \frac{\text{GeV}}{f_{\gamma}}\right)$ and typically oscillates fast with $f_{\gamma}$ in the $<\text{ GeV}$ range, makimg experimental observations hard.

Comment: Here is the recent review of experiments trying to detect axions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00039 .

Comment: @annav : although there are many experiments described in the paper, surprisingly there may be some problems with detecting such strongly interacting axion-like particles. For detecting of solar ALPs, the problem is that they, even if borned inside the sun, can't escape from it because of large coupling $f_{\gamma}$. For LSW and microwave cavity experiments, based on axion-photon conversion in presence of external magnetic field, the problem is that an oscillation probability below $f_{\gamma} =$ O(GeV) quickly oscillates with $f_{\gamma}$, making predictions about $f_{\gamma}$ problematic.

Comment: On the other hand, strongly interacting axions should have been seen at the LHC https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05334

Comment: @annav : it seems that experiments detecting ALPs at the LHC are typically based on detecting of their decays inside detectors after passing a solid barrier, which requires or relatively short vacuum lifetime $\tau \sim f_{\gamma}^2/m_{\theta}^3$ and, possibly, weak coupling (in order to pass the barrier). But ALPs with small masses (of $< 10^-3$ eV and lower, as in my question) has very large lifetime.

Comment: Is this a peer reviewed theory?  It will look like a neutron in the hadronic detectors of the LHC, if it is strongly interacting. Here is a disagreement of neutron production with the models https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03505  . axions?

Comment: @annav : I'm sorry, by the phrase "strongly interacting axion" written in the question I've meaned axion with large EM coupling $1/f_{\gamma}$, defined in $(1)$.

Comment: so what is the interaction, a scatter? it will look like a neutron scatter in the forward detectors, neutrons scatter off protons in the detectors, and nuclei and the scattered particle(s) is detected.

Comment: It will look line a neutron interaction in the electromagnetic calorimeter. i.e. nothing coming in and a track detected in the calorimeter. Or even like a photon, an excess to QED calculations

Comment: @annav : it seems rhat the only interaction which is relevant for experiments and observations, for large coupling and small mass, is axion-photon conversion in presence of external EM field (Primakoff process).

Comment: there are huge magnetic fields in the LHC detectors, also they are massive, so you are saying it would look like a photon hit the detector, so it is an excess over QED calculations. You should calculate the number and functional dependence in pp scattering to give some measure for the experiments to check. Existing monte carlos are very good at background photons.